# Origini dell'interiezione "Ammàzza!"

Tags: regional, etymology, history, interjections, colloquial

Un'interiezione usata in italiano, principalmente in romanesco, è

> *Ammàzza!* o *Ammàzzate!* (o *Ammàzzete!*)

o anche

> *Ammàzza oh!* o *Ammàzzate oh!* (o *Ammàzzete oh!*)

o altre simili varianti (*Ammàzzalo!*, *Ammàzzelo!*, anche al femminile e al plurale).

La canzone del 1973 di Luciano Rossi, *Ammàzzate oh!*, ebbe momenti di gloria (*"non te smove 'na cannonata | hai detto basta e te ne sei annata | ammazzate oh"*).

L'interiezione esprime sorpresa per una situazione esagerata o inattesa.

Non è tuttavia chiaro quali possano esserne le *origini semantiche*, per così dire. Chi ammazza chi, in che senso, e perché?

Intuitivamente verrebbe da pensare: la cosa è così esagerata o inattesa che dopo di essa ci si può solo attendere che *è la fine del mondo*, ci si può anche ammazzare, *è finita*, non c'è altro da fare. Potrebbe essere un'espressione di origine militare, *uccidi, uccidi!*, un letterale incitamento ad uccidere, a reagire in maniera folle ed esagerata (incitamento che nel tempo forse è diventata un'interiezione dal senso ironico).

Queste interpretazioni vanno nella giusta direzione? Ve ne sono altre? Esiste qualche fonte al riguardo? In che periodo l'espressione è stata usata per la prima volta?

---

Finora ho cercato nel *Meo Patacca* di Giuseppe Berneri e non ho trovato riferimenti utili. Ho cercato nei sonetti di Giuseppe Gioachino Belli (dove la radice "*ammazz*" compare un centinaio di volte) e ho trovato un paio di riferimenti, ma non di facile comprensione:

> *ammazz’ammazza sò ttutt’una razza* (detto dei cardinali, nel sonetto 2150, *Er cardinale bbono*)
>
> *«Sette de coppe? Ammazza, Margherita»* (detto durante una partita di briscola, nel sonetto 2264, *La bbriscola*)

(Nel primo esempio *ammazz'ammazza* significa *stringi stringi*. Nel secondo esempio il termine si riferisce ad *ammazzare la briscola*, superare la briscola dell'avversario. Non sono sicuro che gli esempi siano pertinenti).

Comment: *Ammàzza* che domanda!

Answer (score 2):

Nella consulenza linguistica dell'Accademia della Crusca si trova un [articolo sull'origine dell'interiezione *ammazza* e altre espressioni simili](https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/emammazzaem-che-caldo/2801) di Paolo D'Achille e Anna M. Thornton.

Si comincia esponendo l'ipotesi di un lettore per cui questa interiezione avrebbe a che vedere con l'inglese *amazing* e sarebbe entrata nell’uso quando i soldati americani circolavano per Roma nel periodo della liberazione, alla quale si risponde in questo modo:

> L’ipotesi etimologica avanzata dal nostro lettore è suggestiva ma infondata. L’esclamazione *ammàzzate!*, come pure *ammazzalo!*, *ammazzala!*, *ammazzali!* e *ammazzale!* (che nel romanesco si usano più spesso nella forma con e invece che a nella sillaba dopo l’accento: *ammàzzete*, *ammàzzelo*, ecc.), deriva dall’imperativo del verbo *ammazzà(re)*, verbo che si trova anche in altre espressioni esclamative dialettali come *te possin’ammazzatte!*, *va a morì ammazzato!*, usate a volte anche scherzosamente, oppure in funzione apotropaica (cioè per augurare del male in modo da ottenere del bene).

L'origine di queste esclamazioni si situa a fine Ottocento: si usava in frasi che si potevano interpretare come un'esortazione (non da prendere in senso letterale) a uccidere persone di cui si disapprovava il comportamento. È spiegata così:

> La nostra espressione (sulla quale si veda ora D’Achille-Thornton 2020), negli esempi più antichi, che risalgono a fine Ottocento, è accompagnata dai pronomi atoni di terza persona singolare e plurale (*lo*, *la*, *li*, *le*) ed è riferita a persone di cui si disapprova il comportamento, tanto che può essere letta come sviluppo di un’esortazione (ovviamente iperbolica) ad ammazzarle sul serio. Ecco un esempio del genere (che è anche il primo finora reperito), che si riferisce a una donna sposata che ha due amanti:
>
> > Lui paga, lei li pîa cor una mano, / E cco’ cquell’antra poi li dà ar zordato. / – Ammazzela! E ’l marito? – È contentone. (Filippo Chiappini, *Tra ddu’ serve*, 1879)

Ma poi l'uso di queste espressioni si evolve in questo modo:

> Ma ben presto, accanto ai pronomi di terza persona – che vengono riferiti anche a cose – si trova pure quello di seconda singolare (*ammazzate!*) e l’espressione, che quindi non può essere più intesa in senso proprio, passa a esprimere meraviglia e anche ammirazione. La perdita del valore verbale è evidente nella forma col pronome di seconda plurale, che è *ammazzeve!* e non *ammazzateve!* (di rarissimo uso). Ecco alcuni esempi:
>
> > – Che pesa assai? – Ammazzelo si pesa! (Giggi Zanazzo, *Un mortorio a Roma*, 1884; il parlante si riferisce a un cadavere, che quindi non può essere ammazzato)
> >
> > – Ammazzete! Tre pacchi n’ha’ sbafati? / E com’ha’ fatto? (Toto Valeri, *La Cannelora*, 1888)
> >
> > – Cinquina! – Chi l’ha fatta? – Er sor Furgenzio. – / – Ammàzzeve che bucio! – E mò che resta? – / – Mò ciaresta la tommola, silenzio! – (Armando Laffranco, *’Na tommolata*, 1895)

Dal romanesco queste espressioni arrivano all'italiano negli anni Venti del Novecento:

> Negli anni Venti del ventesimo secolo le nostre espressioni dal romanesco passano anche all’italiano:
>
> > – Eccola lì la torre girante! Ammazzala, com’è alta! (Grazia Deledda, *Il sigillo d’amore*, 1926) 
> > Ammazzale che carte schifose! (Ettore Petrolini, *Benedetto tra le donne*, 1927)

Le prime attestazioni dell'interiezione *ammazza!*, però, risalgono agli anni Cinquanta del XX secolo:

> Agli anni Cinquanta risalgono i primi esempi del semplice *ammazza!*, privo di pronomi e con valore decisamente ammirativo, reperibili nei romanzi romani di Pasolini, che documentano pure la forma con il pronome di prima persona singolare *ammazzeme!*, molto rara ma effettivamente possibile, al pari di quella col pronome di prima persona plurale, *ammazzece*, attestata nel poeta romanesco Elia Marcelli, in un poema in ottave scritto negli anni Settanta, in cui rievoca la drammatica Campagna in Russia durante l’ultimo conflitto mondiale:
>
> > Gli altri giovanotti che indugiavano chi nudo, chi con gli slip penzoloni, chi pettinandosi davanti allo specchietto, chi cantando, se li guardavano con la coda dell’occhio come per dire: “Ammazza quanto so’ gajardi”. (Pier Paolo Pasolini, *Ragazzi di vita*, 1955)
> >
> > Agnolo allora prese la rincorsa e si tuffò. “Li mortacci tua!” gridò Marcello vedendolo cadere tutto di sguincio con la pancia. “Ammazzeme”, gridò Agnolo risortendo col capo in mezzo al fiume, “che panzata!”. (ivi)
> >
> > Ammàzzece – fo io – che criminali! / Quanti carci stanotte j’âmo dato!”. (Elia Marcelli, *Li Romani in Russia*, 1988)

E poi *ammazza!* passa dal romanesco all'italiano:

> Con questo significato puramente “mirativo”, *ammazza!* è passato dal romanesco all’italiano, tanto che è da tempo registrato anche dai vocabolari di lingua. Nello Zingarelli 2020 viene datato 1870 (anteriormente dunque alle forme, pure registrate, *ammazzalo* e *ammazzete*, datate rispettivamente 1923 e 1955), ma si tratta di una datazione basata su una falsa attestazione (cfr. D’Achille 2019).

Answer (score 0):

Da buon italiano del centro appennino ti descrivo l'accezione che l'espressione "ammàzza" assume dalle mie parti:

1. Significa che la caratteristica/la situazione/il soggetto/l'oggetto
   osservata/o è talmente esagerato che potrebbe uccidere (spesso in
   senso figurato).
2. Per esempio: "Ammàzza se pìcca 'sto peperoncino..."
       significa tradotto in italiano "questo peperoncino è
       talmente piccante che potrebbe uccidere..."
3. Da quanto sopra, si
       evince quindi con immediatezza, che il soggetto dell'azione
       dell'ammazzare sia la caratteristica/la situazione/il
       soggetto/l'oggetto osservata/o,
4. mentre la vittima potenziale
       potrebbe essere chi si dovesse trovarsi ad affrontare tale soggetto.

Purtroppo non riesco a corroborare la mia risposta con delle citazioni celebri, speriamo che qualcun altro possa contribuire.

Comment: Altrettanto da italiano dell'Italia centrale (Roma) e altrettanto senza fonti, francamente non riesco a “sentire” la locuzione “ammazza” in questo modo, anche perché formalmente è un imperativo rivolto all'interlocutore (e non un indicativo riferito al peperoncino o quel che sia), come è chiarito anche meglio dalla forma “ammàzzate”.

Comment: Da italiano del nord ho la stessa impressione di @DaG per quanto riguarda questa risposta. Mi sembra che cerchi troppo forzatamente un collegamento logico fra "ammazzare" e le frasi di esempio in cui il verbo è inserito. Secondo me i casi in cui l'espressione viene usata in Italia non hanno mai a che fare con l'atto di uccidere (se non per coincidenza, senza nessun legame diretto). A riprova di questo credo si possa affermare che questo uso di "ammazza!" può sempre venire sostituito con "accidenti!" senza che il significato risulti alterato.

Comment: Inoltre a quello detto nei commenti precedenti, non mi sembra che questo post sia una vera risposta alla domanda.

Comment: @SantiBailors: L'origine di questa interiezione ha, in effetti, qualcosa a che vedere con uccidere, ma il rapporto è molto diverso da quello spiegato in questa risposta. Vedi quello che dice l'Accademia della Crusca nell'altra risposta, basato su questo recente studio: P. D’Achille, A. M. Thornton, *Storia di un imperativo divenuto interiezione*: ammazza!, in «*’E parole de Roma*». *Studi di etimologia e lessicologia romanesche*, a cura di Vincenzo Faraoni e Michele Loporcaro, Berlin/Boston, De Gruyter, 2020 (“Beihefte zur Zeitschrift für romanische Philologie”, 445), pp. 163-194.

Answer (score -3):

Credo che, molto semplicemente, il vocabolo abbia origini militari, o comunque legate a un’istigazione all’uccidere, nel senso di ultima spiaggia: “di fronte a tanto non si può rispondere con altro se non con l’uccisione di chi presenta questa cosa fuori dalle regole davanti a noi.” Insomma un invito all’estrema difesa di sé stessi. Potrebbe essere trasmigrata dal gergo della malavita romana oppure, ipotesi più pittoresca, da quello delle antiche legioni romane.

Comment: Scusa, ma questo non è un forum in cui ognuno formula delle ipotesi (“credo che”, “potrebbe”, “ipotesi più pittoresca”), bensì si cercano risposte basate su fonti attestate, come vedi nella risposta di @Charo.